Editing default Internal loadbalancer of azure container apps
When I create an Azure Container Apps environment in a subnet with the setting "Internal: The endpoint is an internal load balancer" enabled, an internal load balancer is created. When I try to change the load balancing rules, it throws a "Failed to update" error. Specifically, I need to modify the session persistence and idle timeout (in minutes) in the rules.
How can I change or override these settings?
Internal Loadbalancer img
Thanks in advance.

Azure's internal load balancer for Azure Container Apps can have limitations on direct modification due to its tight integration with the Azure Container Apps service.

Is there any other way to do those changes?

Changes to the internal load balancer are managed through Container Apps. If you want to modify the load balancer you need to update container apps. Though you do not have the full options exposed through Container Apps.
However, it sounds like you want to disable session affinity. Did you tried setting it over the ingress configuration?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/sticky-sessions?pivots=azure-portal#configure-session-affinity
Unfortunately, the timeout is currently not configurable
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/597
There is currently a preview feature, which seems not help you setting the timeout, but maybe it bring more control over the sessions. But not sure if it really helps you addressing your issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/sessions-custom-container?tabs=azure-cli
